# Capacitor can't filter the AC detector spikes

Tags: arduino, ac, filter, opto-isolator, spike

I made a simple design to read the status of an 220 V AC relay. I used a diode and resistor to drop the voltage for the PC817 optocoupler and used a capacitor to filter spikes:

[image]

This is the test circuit (the electronic capacitor and optocoupler are on the back of the board):

[image]

I used simple code like the following to read the status of the pin:

[image]

It seems no matter what type of capacitor I use, the spikes aren't filtered out properly and this gives me unusable results on the Arduino.

How can I dampen the spike reasonably?

As resistors make heat and would be bulky, if I want to use an array of AC relay inputs and share the parts between the AC detector. Can I use the following schematic and share the common input line between the all detectors so I don't have to use many bulky parts on my board?

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are grounding your Arduino connection. Shouldn't you take your signal off the collector?

Comment: It was a schematic mistake, in the test, I had connected correctly

Answer (score 3):

I had good results with this:

[image]

Problems with your schematic:

- Using resistors to limit current from mains causes unnecessary dissipation, a capacitor dropper wastes much less power.
- Two rectifying diodes in series is not useful, one is enough.
- You're using half wave rectification which means the cap must power the LED for the half period during which the rectifier is off. C18 (1µF) is too small for this. Using a rectifier bridge solves this problem.
- C17 (4pF) has much too small value to do anything useful, should be removed
- There should be a resistor in series with the LED to smooth LED current, otherwise the LED will discharge the cap too quick and you get pulsed output
- Schematic mistake: output should be on the opto's collector

Also your prototype looks pretty deadly...

---

As per your comment: how to make it compact with many inputs.

In order to make it compact, it must not dissipate much power, and avoid large components like high voltage film caps.

[image]

V2 is a microcontroller GPIO output. It is set to output a PWM signal, period 4.5ms, ON-time 100µs. Through the opto X4 this turns on MOSFET X2 in pulses. It should be at least 600V small signal MOSFET.

When the MOSFET is off, C1 charges slowly through R3+R4. When it is on, C1 discharges into the opto X3's LED, giving a current pulse high enough to turn it on well. If mains voltage is present, the result is a pulse on the output, which can be easily checked by the microcontroller.

Comment: I'm going to have an array of AC detectors on my board so the number of components is my concern, I believe your design is very similar to mine as it works without heat, except I forgot to use the filter for Arduino input and  maybe half cycle positive voltage and half cycle near zero voltage (10ms) need to count in

Comment: Your current design has 3x100k in parallel which means 7mA current taken from 230V, so the resistors will dissipate 1.6W which means they have to be pretty bulky. But the current is shared between optos, so if they're all on, they may not get enough current. Also you can replace all the capacitors with software.

Comment: @bobflux FYI In the SPD industry phase taps with capacitors to verify phase is active use 200 ohm to 600 ohm wirewound flameprof resistors to block inrush current and back emf from inductive load that would blow an LED or optocoupler. Not sure this is that critical

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

1. Smooth the signal on the MCU side.
2. Protect the opto-isolator LED with an anti-parallel diode, instead of two series diodes, to ensure that leakage current isn't sufficient to strongly reverse bias the LED.
3. Use the indicator LED as the protection diode in point 2 above.
4. Don't use resistors in parallel to spread power dissipation. Use resistors in series, to share both power *and* voltage between them.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUJk1H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I suspect that when you say "spikes" you are referring to rectified pulses. If not, and you mean there are serious short-duration high voltage spikes that exceed the normal 310V peak potential difference, then employ a bi-directional TVS diode (or back-to-back zener diodes) to protect the LEDs:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZrVWO.png)</sup>

As for sharing components between multiple channels, I don't immediately see how that could work, considering that each LED requires a prescribed amount of current. Any solution would ideally have to avoid sharing available current between LEDs, causing LED current to diminish with each added channel. At best you would have to increase total available current in the first place, which would necessarily dissipate more power in every resistor.

Perhaps someone else can think of a way to adapt the above without having those problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the cause of your spikes are. Is it from the switching or from the AC line itself? Below is a circuit that I used to detect AC mains with reduced parts count by using an optocoupler with AC input. There are many part numbers out there that have back-to-back led's at the input. You would probably need to adjust the values for 230VAC as mine is designed for 120V. The ferrite bead helps when using this signal on a wire; probably not needed if it is on the same board as the microcontroller.

[image: AC mains detector]

You should try to have a look with an oscilloscope if you have access to one. This will help troubleshooting a lot. You can then look at the pulse width of the spike to figure out what might reduce that frequency of noise. Simon has a good point of adding a bi-directional TVS after the current limiting resistors. This may help if it has something to do with switching noise. I think increasing the capacitor on the output side will help as well, but this will increase the response time to any transitions on the line. You will have to see what works.

When working with high voltage, you should use multiple resistors in series rather than parallel because they have a limited working voltage, usually less than 200V, while 230VAC has a working voltage of about 325V. So two or three resistors is a safer design. Also, you should definitely have a low-amp fuse, like 0.2 or 0.5A to reduce any damage by accidents. Lastly, I would wrap any high-voltage exposed leads in electrical tape as it would be easy to zap something or yourself. 230V is no joke.